# Indian eBusiness visa issues

Tags: visas, india, business-travel

I have a business trip in India on January 25 to February 10. The eVisa website keeps crashing on me. Pages keep saying "Session Timed Out" when I save them, meaning that I have to keep trying over and over until it allows me to save.

Then I had issues uploading photos. It refused to accept the photos I supplied, even though I followed all the naming, photography, size and file format standards. Then the Session Timed Out on me again, and when trying to pick up at the last saved point, various required fields, such as "Exit Point from India", were blank and uneditable.

Should I start a new eBusiness visa application from the beginning, or should I just go for an eTourist visa?

It would take at least 3-5 business days to process a regular (hard copy) visa with the Indian High Commission in Canberra, so that's probably not an option for me.

Comment: You definitely do have enough time to get a proper visa in case all else fails.

Comment: file size matter. You may need to save with more compression. Note: passport photo and your photo need to be in two different formats: do not ask why! (or this was done in the past: one pdf, and one jpg).